# Setting foreground of TextBlock to a LinearGradientBrush causes unwanted behavior

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm getting unwanted behavior from a `TextBlock` I'm using in my `DataTemplate`. It seems that the `LinearGradientBrush` that I'm using for the `Foreground` property is not drawing the gradient consistantly across the font for words that contain "descenders" like the lower-case 'p' in the word Vampire in the example picture.

I tried setting the `LineHeight` to the same as the `FontSize`; no change.
I tried setting the `Height` of the `TextBlock`; no change to the color, but added height to the bottom of the `TextBlock`.

Has anyone else dealt with this and found a solution before? I tried searching Google and StackOverflow for answers but I've come up with nothing so far.

**Edit:** The problem is the gradient is not applied the same to each textbox, because the descenders increase the height of the font. Look at the difference between the lower-case 'a' in the words `Vampire` and `Brave`, and you will see what I mean.

[image: Detailed ultra-cool example image]

## `TextBlock` XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" 
           FontSize="20" Padding="3" LineHeight="20">
  <TextBlock.Foreground>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
      <GradientStopCollection>
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.2"/>
        <GradientStop Color="AliceBlue" Offset="0.4"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#6AB0EE" Offset="0.6"/>
        <GradientStop Color="DarkOrange" Offset="0.8"/>
      </GradientStopCollection>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </TextBlock.Foreground>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what the problem is. The image looks exactly the same as defined in XAML. your brush starts with white at .2 and ends with DarkOrange at .8 (which will also make the remaining .2 DarkOrange)

Comment: @HighCore Look at the lower-case 'a' in the word Vampire compared to the lower-case 'a' in the word Brave. The gradient is not applied the same, because the textblock containing 'Vampire' has a word that contains a 'descender', 'p'. I consider that the problem. I want the font to look like the word 'Brave' does, regardless of if it contains any descenders.

Comment: Interesting problem. This seems like a case of it working as designed, where the design doesn't quite accommodate this common scenario. The addition of a character with descender ('p') increases the height of the `Glyph` in the `TextBlock`, thus changing the way a gradient will apply to it. One possible (ugly) workaround would be to use separate `Run`s within the `TextBlock` for descender characters. Another might be to use `FormattedText`.

Comment: @KentBoogaart Rafal figured it out. If you set the MappingMode of the LinearGradientBrush to Absolute, you can then set the StartPoint and EndPoint to basically define a height for the gradient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set `MappingMode` property like this:

```
<LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
```

Comment: I used `EndPoint="0,26"` and `MappingMode="Absolute"` and I am able to get the desired look! With `EndPoint="0,1"`, the entire text was orange (the last gradientstop color), so I realized that I needed to set the endpoint to be the height of the textblock! Thank you!